# How to dump / restore mysql.user

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqldump

I'm able to dump the table of users from one server with

```
mysqldump -u root -p -h [host address] mysql user > user_table_dump.sql
```

but how can I restore these users into my localhost enviroment? I tried without success:

```
mysql -u root -p mysql.user < user_table_dump.sql
```

```
mysql -u root -p mysql user < user_table_dump.sql
```

```
mysqldump -u root -p -h localhost mysql user < user_table_dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment by [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina):

> Edit dump file, remove all DDL statements from it. Restore data only - `LOCK TABLES`user`WRITE; INSERT INTO`user`VALUES ... ; UNLOCK TABLES;`.

I did it by taking only the data saved on the file and insert them into mysql.user like

```
INSERT INTO mysql.user VALUES(...)
```